# JSON Schema to compare two arrays have same values

Tags: jsonschema

Say we have...

```
{
   "abc": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
   "xyz": [ { "i": 1, "j": 10 }, { "i": 2, "j": 20 }, { "i": 3, "j": 30 } ]
}
```

Is it possible for a schema to validate that for every value in "abc", there is also an object in xyz where field "i" has that same value (and vice-versa)?

Seems straight-forward, but I haven't cracked it yet.

Comment: This kind of restriction is not possible using JsonSchema. If the array *abc* is a fixed enumeration then it would be possible to ensure that all *i* values belong to the enumeration. But that is not what you are asking.